# Problem in Confirm Dialog using commandButton PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I have a form and i want that the user press "Save" button display a Confirm Dialog, even this step everything works well, display Dialog, when user press "Save", PrimeFaces validate required files, but when user (me) press again "Save" button, Confirm Dialog no longer appears and refresh .xhtml.

Anyone know what´s going on?

This is my .xhtml

```
<h:form id="frmUser">

   <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{user.name}" required="true"/>
   <p:fileUpload id="photofile"                         
    value="#{user.fileUpload}"
    mode="simple"                           
    required="true"
    accept=".pdf" />

   <p:commandButton id="accept"  value="Accept"  onclick="PF('confirmation').show();" ></p:commandButton>

  <p:confirmDialog  message="Are you sure want to continue?" appendToBody="true"                 
                 widgetVar="confirmation">
        <p:commandButton 
              value="Yes" mode="simple" ajax="false" process="@all"
              action="#{user.save(1)}"
              update="userName photofile" />
        <p:commandButton value="No" oncomplete="PF('confirmation').hide()" />
  </p:confirmDialog>    

</h:form>
```

And this is my Bean

```
@Named("user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable{

   private String name;
   private  UploadedFile fileUpload;

  //Getters and Setters

   public void save(int sel){}

}
```

My idea is submit input "Name" and File at the same time using mode="simple" and ajax="false"

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Have a good look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml and make sure you are doing the same.

Comment: Compare with the PrimeFaces showcase, it all works there.

Comment: Hahaha... then the suggestion must be really good